# Nativescript image capture issue

Tags: angular6, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I'm using Native script angular for my application. I need a camera and file browse feature.

I have tried the below two plugins for the camera feature

1. https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-camera

But it is not supported me. It throws the below error

[image]

I have modified the App_Resources/AndroidManifest.xml file with the below content which I have seen this solution in some forums. But this is also not get fixed.

`<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.*.*.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" tools:replace="android:authorities" > <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" tools:replace="android:resource" ></provider>`

Please suggest me to fix this issue.

13/Dec/18

Still Im in stuck.

[image]

Comment: Those plugins do not need any customisation on `AndroidManifest.xml`, may I know why you are adding this? What is your version of NativeScript?

Comment: Hi @Manoj 
Native script version - 4.2.4. I have searched to find the solution in different forums. They mentioned this provider code to work camera feature.

Comment: Remove those changes in manifest, either upgrade to latest version of {N} or downgrade your plugin version to keep it inline with the {N} version you are using.

Comment: Tried by downgrading the nativescript-camera from 4.1.1 to 4.0.3. that's not working.

Comment: You are supposed to do that with nativescript-camera-plus plugin as you see in the error log the issue belongs there. If you are not using camera plus but just camera plug-in then remove it.